# Replace end of string when start matched

Tags: regex, string, replace

This is what I have in first file:

```
16;01978B66;BC101;FALSE
17;0195B4E5;BC101;FALSE
18;019796C6;BC101;FALSE
19;0197D016;BC101;FALSE
```

This is what I have in 2nd file

```
16;01978B66;BC102;FALSE
17;0195B4E5;BC102;FALSE
18;019796C6;BC102;FALSE
19;0197D016;BC102;FALSE
```

What regex should I use if I want to replace end of every line starting with 16; and 18; , from ;FALSE to ;TRUE ? I would like to use notepad++ replace in files, so I can replace multiple lines 16; and 18; in all files without touching middle of the string with different values.

I understand regex once I get it explained but I searched for hours and I get lost in other examples...

This is what I should get:

```
16;01978B66;BC101;TRUE
17;0195B4E5;BC101;FALSE
18;019796C6;BC101;TRUE
19;0197D016;BC101;FALSE
```

and

```
16;01978B66;BC102;TRUE
17;0195B4E5;BC102;FALSE
18;019796C6;BC102;TRUE
19;0197D016;BC102;FALSE
```

I tried to capture in 3 groups with

```
^(17;)[a-zA-Z0-9\;]{9}[a-zA-Z0-9\;]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9\;]{5}
```

but replace with ($3);TRUE`is leaving me with only`;TRUE` which is not good.

This must be piece of cake for someone who knows how to replace end of string.

btw 0197D016;BC101;  is constant in lenght, `8 digits ;  2letters3numbers ;`

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

> Find what:    `^((16|18);.+?)FALSE$`
>
> Replace with: `$1TRUE`

Comment: Can we fix this find formula, to have separate values? 
Sometime i need numbers like 15 16 64 182 they dont have common numbers...
'^(16;|18;.+?)FALSE$'  finds only 18;

Comment: I updated the expression to list the individual numbers.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your time, this will save me a lot of time!